# JavaScript workers seems not running in background

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have this JavaScript worker for fetching data on the PHP backend.

ajax-worker.js

```
self.onmessage = function(e){

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            postMessage(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", e.data, true);
    xhttp.send();

}
```

and initiate a worker by

```
let worker = new window.Worker('http://localhost:8100/ajax-worker.js');

worker.postMessage('http://localhost:8100/Audit/get_total_confirmed');

worker.onmessage = function(e){
    var e = JSON.parse(e.data);
    document.querySelector('#stat_confirmed_listings').innerHTML = e.msg;
}
```

Everything is working except if I browse other pages in my website, it takes very long time to load and sometimes it returns "unreachable page" error and not until the worker completes the request or restart the server, the page then will load. What might be wrong?

Below is the view of my console `console -> sources`:

[image]

Comment: maybe you use up all connection?

Comment: and what you mean by `browse other pages`?

Comment: @appleapple like from http://localhost:8100 that hosted my app, then I will to go http://localhost:8100/about

Comment: @appleapple can you enlighten me about "use up all connection" please.

Comment: if you open `network` panel in devtool, you can see more about how each request going on.

Comment: by use up all connection, I mean (iirc) chrome only allow 6 or so connection at same time per site, and you have 5 worker with may already take most of quota. Depending on the site structure, this may cause problem.

Comment: Why do you even use a worker for this? The network request will take like zero CPU, only the parsing of the response will, and you'll do that anyway when deserializing the message from the worker. You really win nothing having such a worker. Also it seems you are starting one new worker per request, a Web Worker is not a simple js object, it's a full agent, with a full JS realm and its own event loop etc., it takes time to start and resources to maintain, you should use it very sporadically when you are sure the operation it will do are worth it.